# Prevent Docker from installing python package requirements on every build (without requirements.txt)

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, setuptools

I'm building an image from a Dockerfile where my main program is a python application that has a number of dependencies. The application is installed via `setup.py` and the dependencies are listed inside. There is no `requirements.txt`. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid having to download and build all of the application dependencies, which rarely change, on every image build. I saw a number of solutions that use the `requirements.txt` file but I'd like to avoid having one if possible.

Comment: Why would you avoid using requirements.txt ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `requires.txt` from the egg info to preinstall the requirements.

```
WORKDIR path/to/setup/script
RUN python setup.py egg_info
RUN pip install -r pkgname.egg-info/requires.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is: if those dependencies rarely change as you said what you could do is another image with already those packages installed. You would create that image and then save it using **`docker save`**, so you end with a new base image with the required dependencies. **`docker save`** will create a **.tar** with the image. You have to load the image using **`docker load`** and then in your **`Dockerfile`** you would do:

```
FROM <new image with all the dependencies>
//your stuff and no need to run pip install
....
```

Hope it helps

[Docker save description](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)